# Realm (v3.5.0) throws exception when accessing db if 'android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"' is included in Android Manifest

Tags: android, realm

I am working on an android POS device that requires that I include `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system` 
in the manifest before I can access the oem's libraries. I am using Realm(3.5.0) as my ORM. But the app keeps crashing every time I try to access the Realm DB with this Error:

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Permission denied in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 252
```

The full error log below:

> 11-05 21:35:29.603 1770-1770/com.tctpos.tpos W/com.tctpos.tpos: type=1400 audit(0.0:9302): avc: denied { create } for name="access_control.new_commit.cv" scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_app_data_file:s0 tclass=fifo_file permissive=0
>   11-05 21:35:29.603 1770-1770/com.tctpos.tpos W/com.tctpos.tpos: type=1400 audit(0.0:9303): avc: denied { create } for name="realm_2628177326.cv" scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_app_data_file:s0 tclass=fifo_file permissive=0
>   11-05 21:35:29.616 1770-1770/com.tctpos.tpos E/REALM_JNI: jni: ThrowingException 5, Permission denied in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 252, .
>   11-05 21:35:29.616 1770-1770/com.tctpos.tpos E/REALM_JNI: Exception has been thrown: Unrecoverable error. Permission denied in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 252
>   11-05 21:35:29.618 1770-1770/com.tctpos.tpos D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   11-05 21:35:29.622 1770-1770/com.tctpos.tpos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  Process: com.tctpos.tpos, PID: 1770
>                                                                  io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. Permission denied in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 252
>                                                                      at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
>                                                                      at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.(SharedRealm.java:186)
>                                                                      at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:239)
>                                                                      at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:202)
>                                                                      at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:298)
>                                                                      at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:284)
>                                                                      at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:281)
>                                                                      at com.vicpin.krealmextensions.RealmExtensionsKt.queryFirst(RealmExtensions.kt:40)
>                                                                      at com.tctpos.tpos.entities.TerminalSettingsDaoImpl.get(TerminalSettings.kt:15)
>                                                                      at com.tctpos.tpos.activities.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.kt:31)
>                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6012)
>                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5348)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)

I really need help, how do I get around this?

Comment: You should file an issue on https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues and specify the **specific device** and the specific Realm version. You can also try a newer Realm version, like 4.1.1 for example.

Comment: Thanks, will do that.

Comment: @Ayodeji Any solution for this issue?